# problem in Get the value of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I send information to the page via livewire and display it via jQuery in loop.

```
<ul class="custom-control-group" id="networlist">

</ul>

    <script>
            let networks
            window.addEventListener('networksEvent' , event => {
                networks = event.detail.networks;
            });
            $(window).on('load', function() {
                $.each(networks, function( index, network ) {
                    var checked = index == 0 ? "checked" : ''
                    $('#networlist').append('<li>' +
                        '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-pro no-control">'+
                        '<input type="radio" '+checked+'  class="custom-control-input" name="coinNetwork" value="'+network.id+'" id="'+network.id+'">'+
                        '<label class="custom-control-label english" for="'+network.id+'">'+network.name+'</label>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</li>');
                });
            });

            $('.coinNetwork').on('change', function(event) {
                console.log($('input[name=coinNetwork]:checked', '#networlist').val())
            });
    </script>
```

But when I click on the radio button, nothing happens and it does not show me the value in the console.. what is problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your selector, I see `$('.coinNetwork')` yet I do not see an element with this Class. I do see a Name attribute that matches.

Comment: @Twisty thanks bro. What should I write instead of coinNetwork?
I saw a lot of example in get the value of radio button, but none of it worked

Comment: If you're trying to select that Radio Item, it would be `$("input[name='coinNetwork']")`

Comment: @Twisty The problem is that I receive network information from LiveWire, and if I set the networks variable manually, the problem is solved.

But it should not be manual.
 How should this problem be solved from Livewire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already had the correct selector inside your final `console.log` but you bind the event a little too late, because the list does not exist when you try to bind it. Either move the event handler inside your `load` handler, or handle it dynamically:

```js
let networks = [{id: 1, name: 'network1'}, {id: 2, name: 'network2'}];
   
  $(window).on('load', function() {
      $.each(networks, function( index, network ) {
          var checked = index == 0 ? "checked" : ''
          $('#networlist').append('<li>' +
              '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-pro no-control">'+
              '<input type="radio" '+checked+'  class="custom-control-input" name="coinNetwork" value="'+network.id+'" id="'+network.id+'">'+
              '<label class="custom-control-label english" for="'+network.id+'">'+network.name+'</label>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</li>');
      });
    $('input[name=coinNetwork]').on('click', function(event) {
      console.log($('input[name=coinNetwork]:checked', '#networlist').val())
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="custom-control-group" id="networlist">
```

For binding to a dynamically added element:

```js
let networks = [{id: 1, name: 'network1'}, {id: 2, name: 'network2'}]
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $.each(networks, function( index, network ) {
    var checked = index == 0 ? "checked" : ''
    $('#networlist').append('<li>' +
                            '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-pro no-control">'+
                            '<input type="radio" '+checked+'  class="custom-control-input" name="coinNetwork" value="'+network.id+'" id="'+network.id+'">'+
                            '<label class="custom-control-label english" for="'+network.id+'">'+network.name+'</label>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</li>');
  });
});

//bind it to networlist
$('#networlist').on('click', 'input[name=coinNetwork]', function(event) {
  console.log($('input[name=coinNetwork]:checked', '#networlist').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="custom-control-group" id="networlist">
```

Also notice I changed the event from `change` to `click` so you get the correct selected value (instead of the last one).

Comment: This is absolutely true. But I get the information from the livewire component
How can I get them faster?
Networks are not the same and we have to receive user-specific networks

Comment: I added my own networks so I can have something to work with. You dont have to change the way in which you get your networks.

Comment: I think I understand your issue now. Are you trying to add the elements to the `ul` after the network loads? Then you have to move that portion of the code to the `networksEvent` handler instead of inside your `load` handler.